# Can i pass a string that contains value taken from database in preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

I need to get values after a specific string in a text.

i.e.,

```
PHONE NUMBER  09878839934
CITY CHENNAI 
EMAIL indhuk23@gmail.com
```

I need to save the values using php.I plan to do it this way :

I match the 'PHONE NUMBER" string in the text..take the values after it till "CITY".
And then match "CITY" ..take values till "EMAIL".
And den the last value.

And moreover the format changes for every email id.
So i actually get the format from a database that has a format based on the email.

Can you help me out?

*EDIT*

The text is an email recieved into my inbox.As i get every email i need to check the "from" id.Based on the from the format differs. So as an email is recieved need to check for the "from id" in the database.And i get the contents of the db as to what format the mail will be.Based on that i need to retrieve values from the message.

*EDIT*
Example:

My table will look like this :

```
email      field1      field2  field3      field4        field5
***.com      Name       City    Service     Phone Number  Preference
***.com Customer Name   Place   Looking for   Mobile      service Preference
```

Comment: What database are you talking about here?

Comment: @codeHeart The format of the text is going to be different based on the e mail id..So i ve stored the format in  a mysql db..i.e., the field names (phone number,city,email (or it can just be NUMBER,PLACE,MAIL for another mail id)itself is stored as values in the db)..

Comment: Maybe you can narrow down your question a bit... it seems quite broad

Comment: Okay..I jus need to get the values from the text...How do i do it using preg functions?

Comment: Are those database fields contains the regex to execute or if PHP is supposed to guess the regex from the content of the field?

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque the db fields does not contain the regex..So i need to convert the values to regex ! Thats the big problem i face here..

Comment: Can you post an example of format? I answered based on your input text, but if that can differ and you don't tell us how, it's quite difficult to guess

Comment: @AlessandroNiciforo Thank you for the effort!! I ve edited to put in examples!!

Comment: Okay.. i found a way to do this..I ll get the format frm the table and then get values as contents between field1 to field2..field2 to field 3....field 3 to field 4...field4 to field5..BUt is there a way to split a string in regex by specifying the start and end?

Answer (score 1):

You could as well use named capture gropus, like so:

```
^PHONE\sNUMBER\s+(?P<phone>.+)\R
CITY\s(?P<city>.+)\R
EMAIL\s(?P<email>.+)
```

In `PHP`, this would be:

```
$regex = '~
          ^PHONE\sNUMBER\s+(?P<phone>.+)\R
          CITY\s(?P<city>.+)\R
          EMAIL\s(?P<email>.+)~mx';

preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// now you can loop over the matches
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo $match["city"]; // etc.
}
```

See a <kbd>[demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vM9iP5/1)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your input text is as in your example (space and new lines), you need something like this:

```
$text = "PHONE NUMBER  09878839934
CITY CHENNAI 
EMAIL indhuk23@gmail.com";

$pattern = "/PHONE NUMBER (.*)\RCITY (.*)\REMAIL (.*)/";
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches); // indexes 1,2 and 3 are phone number, city and email
```

Comment: i'd used `\R` to match all the kind of line break `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n` just to be safe since he said that he is receiving data by emails.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$username="root";$password="";$database="format";
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$ead="quikr.com";
$query=mysql_query("select * from mail where email ='$ead'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$f1 = $row['field1'];
$f2 = $row['field2'];
$f3 = $row['field3'];
$f4 = $row['field4'];
$f5 = $row['field5'];
$f6 = $row['field6'];
$input="Name\n\nSindhuj City :Chennai- Service Pest ID mail.com Phone Number 9043234342 Preference redident";
$input=preg_replace('/\R/','', $input);
$input=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', ' ', $input);
//$fone='/\b['.$f1.','.$f2.','.$f3.','.$f4.','.$f5.','.$f6.']+\b/i';
$fone='/'.$f1.'(.*?)'.$f2.'/';
preg_match($fone,$input, $display);
print_r($display[1]);
$ftwo='/'.$f2.'(.*?)'.$f3.'/';
preg_match($ftwo,$input, $display);
print_r($display[1]);
$ftwo='/'.$f3.'(.*?)'.$f4.'/';
preg_match($ftwo,$input, $display);
print_r($display[1]);
$ftwo='/'.$f4.'(.*?)'.$f5.'/';
preg_match($ftwo,$input, $display);
print_r($display[1]);
$ftwo='/'.$f5.'(.*?)'.$f6.'/';
preg_match($ftwo,$input, $display);
print_r($display[1]);
?>
```